# is it possible for a Chatbot in Dialogflow to read content from a website and make interactions accordingly?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to create Chatbot in Dialogflow to read content from a website and make interactions accordingly is it possible if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, you can use Cheerio and request etc to web scrape. And then you can run code on the pages you have scraped.

add these to the top of your code

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const req = require('request');
```

and then add these to the dependencies

```
"cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2"
"request": "^2.88.0"
```

then scrape a webpage

```
req('www.google.co.uk', function(err, resp, html) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          const $ = cheerio.load(html, {
            normalizeWhitespace: true,
            xmlMode: true
          });
```

and then do whatever with the code. cheerio borrows the jQuery syntax. more on that here
http://zetcode.com/javascript/cheerio/